# PHP Function Inside of An Array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Here is what I have so far:

```
$arrayPrices = array(
    translate($lang_type, "A/C System Evaluation") => "19.95",
    translate($lang_type, "A/C Evaluation & Recharge") => "99.00"
);
```

And my **translate function** is:

```
function translate($to_lan, $text) {
if($to_lan == "en") {

    return $text;

} else {

    $translate_feed = @file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=' . BING_APPID . '&text=' . urlencode($text) . '&from=en&to=' . $to_lan . '');
    $translate = simplexml_load_string($translate_feed);

    return ($translate_feed === false) ? $text : $translate[0];
   }
 }
```

For some reason, I can't display that translate function inside of my PHP Array.

If I type in `echo translate($lang_type, "A/C System Evaluation");`  it works just fine and translates.  But when used in that array it just returns blank.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Syntactically correct, so might be some side-effects like uninitialized state, or the second request being blocked. You certainly shouldn't initialize the array from remote API calls. Especially if some of those values might never be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP Array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.

Put your keys in string vars first,like:

```
$var1 = translate($lang_type, "A/C System Evaluation");
$var2 = translate($lang_type, "A/C Evaluation & Recharge");

$arrayPrices = array(
    "$var1" => 19.95
    "$var2" => 29.95
);
```

That should work fine.

Comment: You can simply cast the result of calling `translate` to a string directly with `(string) translate(...) => ...` or [`strval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).

Comment: @DavidHarkness There are many ways to go about it, this is the simplest IMO which I thought the op would appreciate. Why not post an answer of your own?

Comment: Your answer addressed the problem--that the values returned by `transate` are not strings. I am only pointing out simpler methods of creating a string from those values. You should still get the credit. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I tried before to put it in a variable but I didn't put the quotes around it which is why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 1):

does this work:

```
$arrayPrices[translate($lang_type, "A/C System Evaluation")]= "19.95";
$arrayPrices[translate($lang_type, "A/C Evaluation & Recharge")] = "99.00";
```

Comment: I think you've got an extra set of brackets in there - that's going to build a 2-D array.

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work for me when I return a class that implements `__toString`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to be able to add extensively to that product list without having to mess around with temporary variables a great deal.  This is one of those situations where I'd do a post-processing run on the array, like so:

```
$arrayPrices = array(
    "A/C System Evaluation" => "19.95",
    "A/C Evaluation & Recharge" => "99.00",
    // ... etcetera ...
);

$keys = array_keys( $arrayPrices );    
foreach( $keys as $keyText )
{
    $translatedKeyText = translate($lang_type, $keyText);
    if ( $translatedKey != $keyText )
    {
        $arrayPrices[$translatedKeyText] = $arrayPrices[$keyText];
        unset( $arrayPrices[$keyText] );
    }
}
```

If you use temporary variables, you'll have to add logic for every new entry to your original array.  That sounds like a maintenance hassle to me.